# What is this code in JS <*, *>?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql

I was looking at the Graphql mutation source code and I see this code, I don't know what to search this, I see `<any>` and `<T>` below, what is this?

```js
    type mutationFn = (
      object: any,
      ctx: any,
      info: GraphQLResolveInfo
    ) => Promise<any> | any;
    
    function resolveMaybeThunk<T>(thingOrThunk: Thunk<T>): T {
      return typeof thingOrThunk === 'function' ? thingOrThunk() : thingOrThunk;
    }
    type MutationConfig = {
      name: string,
      description?: string,
      deprecationReason?: string,
      inputFields: Thunk<GraphQLInputFieldConfigMap>,
      outputFields: Thunk<GraphQLFieldConfigMap<*, *>>,
      mutateAndGetPayload: mutationFn,
    };
```

What does it do when a code is wrapped with `<code>`?

Comment: This is not vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: This is TypeScript.

Comment: That's Typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: and it is a Type definition. GraphQLFieldConfigMap is an Map of any Type

Comment: This is a TypeScript generic type. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html